# What is the purpose of the virtual store and its parent (node_modules), in pnpm?

Tags: npm, pnpm

I [read this article](https://dev.to/stackblitz/what-is-pnpm-and-is-it-really-so-fast-and-space-efficient-29la) about the pnpm arcitecture, and found the picture helpful:

[image]

When inspecting my own project's `node_modules` folder (it uses pnpm), I see symlinks directly within it, as well as a `node_modules/.pnpm` folder with hard links to the content-addressable (aka. global) store.

**My question is**: When does pnpm place soft/hard links in the `node_modules/.pnpm` folder, vs directly in the `node_modules` folder? What is the difference between the two? Why does it use the `node_modules` folder directly, instead of placing all the links in the `node_modules/.pnpm` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pnpm is putting symlinks to the root of `node_modules`. Only direct dependencies are symlinked to the root of `node_modules`: packages that are listed in `dependencies`/`devDependencies`/`optionalDependencies` of your project's `package.json` file.

> Why does it use the node_modules folder directly, instead of placing all the links in the node_modules/.pnpm folder?

Because when in your code you have a `require` statement, Node.js is looking for the required package inside the root of `node_modules`. It is not looking inside `node_modules/.pnpm`. Node.js finds the package inside the virtual store because pnpm creates a symlink that points to a directory inside the virtual store.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Is this correct then: 1) All packages are saved in the content addressable store (aka. CAS | global store). 2) *Indirect dependencies* are hard-linked from the virtual store to the CAS. 3) *Direct dependencies* are soft-linked from node_modules to the virtual store and from there hard-linked to the CAS.

Comment: I have a few files in a next monorepo project's `node_modules` without a symlink symbol next to it in the vscode file explorer. Most do have the symlkink symbol, but some do not. Any idea why there seems to be a mix in there?

Comment: sounds correct

If the directories start with a dot then it might be stuff like `.cache` created by some tooling. If there are some dependencies that are not symlinked then probably they were created by another package manager. pnpm doesn't use a hybrid approach. It either uses symlinks or writes the real files when `node-linker` is set to `hoisted`.